# Autorun console application in linux

Tags: c#, linux, autorun

I have developed a console application using MVS and I compiled it so can run on linux.

It runs on linux when I manually run and everything works so far. But whenever I try to run it at boot using crontab it seems not to be working.

My application is a HttpListener. The linux environment I run this is a robot's. I've not used linux very much so I have found and used the below commands to get this run at boot.

```
@reboot /home/rauman/Downloads/webserver
```

Then I tried setting a delay of 20secs,

```
@reboot sleep 20 && /home/rauman/Downloads/webserver
```

I normally run this application with terminal like below and works fine

```
./webserver
```

I'm accessing the robot using **putty**

After adding this to run at boot, I could see the pid of the application,

```
pidof webserver
```

So I guess it runs, but got no permission or something?

I have given permission for the file using,

```
chmod +x webserver
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit : Solved

As, Mr. R pointed out

```
@reboot sleep 20 && cd /home/rauman/Downloads/ && /.webserver
```

Comment: Have you tried running `/home/rauman/Downloads/webserver` from a random pwd and watching console logs?

Comment: @Mr.R what do you mean by pwd? sorry, I'm not much familiar with linux. I did run with terminal and crontab only. However when using crontab I don't know how to access the console with terminal to see what it prints

Comment: I think your `webserver` is somehow related to the current path of the working directory (pwd)! As you said, it works when you open a terminal in the `/home/rauman/Downloads/` directory and run `./webserver`. Now please open a new terminal somewhere else (e.g in /etc dir) and try to run it by the same command as you are using in crontab (`/home/rauman/Downloads/webserver`). You can get the terminal working directory using the `pwd` command. If it doesn't work, you can change crontab to `@reboot sleep 20 && cd /home/rauman/Downloads/ && /.webserver`.

Comment: @Mr.R You are correct! When my app started, it reads a file first and fetch some data. So when I run it using the crontab, it's not looking for the same location. I had to change /.webserver to ./webserver. Could you please put your answer as an answer so I can mark it as correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem a few days ago. My app runs flawlessly when I call it from its working directory but it failed when getting called from outside. It turned out the app reads a file by a relative address. So I had to change either the program or the pwd.

The easiest way that I came by is changing pwd:

```bash
@reboot sleep 20 && cd /home/rauman/Downloads/ && ./webserver
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I haven't used linux previously, specially the terminal. I was clueless and found the crontab. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`crontab` runs processes as `root`, so any another file (such configurations) beloning to your user profile folder cannot be accessibile by `¢rotab`.

Is this you scenario?

If yes, you should them into `/etc` or into `/root`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's as if Mr. R pointed out. My app is reading a file in it's location, so when I start it using crontab, the location changes and my app attempt to read the file in another location. @reboot sleep 20 && cd /home/rauman/Downloads/ && ./webserver did the trick :)